# Users, Roles and Permissions where some roles can have a combination of permissions

Tags: mysql, user-permissions, user-roles

Take a look at the sketch below. How can I have a "dynamic" role for `limited_administrator`? I want to be able to assign to different users the role of `limited_administrator` but that each of them being able to have access to a different combination of Modules.

Example:

```
user_limited_administrator:
   access Module 1, access Module 2  
payments_limited_administrator:
   access Module 1, access Module 4, access Module 5  
customer_representative_limited_administrator:
   access Module 3, access Module 4, access module 5  

... and other combinations based on future project needs
```

Do I need to add to the roles table all the `limited_administrator` accounts that I need to use and assign to the user that specific `limited_administrator` role? Is there another way?

P.S: my "user" role also has to be split into 3 or 4 subtypes as the `limited_administrator` would be.

[image]

**Edit:** I found [this question and an amazing answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12107/11075) that may solve most of my issues.

[image]

Can this approach use an incremental type of user role permissions (build on from the other). Consider these permissions: search, post, comment, manage users. I want to have: guest (search), user (search, post, comment), admin(search, post, comment, manage users). Can I say this: guest (search), user is guest + (post, comment), admin is user + (manage users)? Would this be a programming mess?

Comment: I think you might be breaking up the role system you've set up. If the notion of a _limited administrator_ has a particular meaning, would it not be better to add new named roles for different module requirements?

Comment: That said, I have seen this problem solved by additionally creating a `user_permissions` table, so that some user abilities can be added individually, in addition to the permissions implied by the `roles` table.

Comment: @halfer Regarding your second comment. Wouldn't that create total mess when the project gets very big. So if one user logs in, I would get their role and their role_permissions, after which I would have to check if they have extra user_permissions?

Comment: No. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think your comment implies that you will be checking all of these tables in various places in your project. That would indeed be a mess! All you should do is check whether the user holds the permission for the thing you are going to do. So if you want to change a user's password, only check that they have `9. Password change` in the permissions table. They may have that from a role or from a direct permission, but that code can be centralised in your user model.

Comment: In fact, the relationship between a feature and a permission can largely be automated - either in a routing system, a controller init phase, or a middleware module. The only permission checking you need to do manually is sub-page-level permissions (a page section appears if you have the permission) or data-level permissions (you can do something depending on a data value).

Comment: Regarding your edit, no - it's the same as what you have at present.

Comment: Well, it's not the same because I was thinking of a one to one relationship between users and roles, while the example showed me that I can also do a one-to-many relationship. However I am still baffled if I should implement multiple roles and assign only one to one user or if I should assign multiple roles to one user

Comment: Ah, in that case your first diagram is wrong - this clearly shows that `users` to `roles` is many:many via `user_roles`. You can still use this schema such that each user has one and only one role, but in your design you do not have to. If you had wanted that limitation, the `role_id` would have gone in the `user` table directly, and the bridge table would be dropped.

Comment: (I think you are worrying about it too much - stick with the many:many approach, and get it working with real users. The schema is flexible enough that you can swap one big role for several small roles, using a script, if you wish later on. My only advice would be that if you have a large number of roles that are only being used by one user, there's probably a shorter way to create your full role set).

Comment: Thanks for four input. I think i have found my solution. Many to many on user and roles and many to many on roles and permissions. I will aim to have one role per user but at least I will have the option to build on that if needed.